# jQuery issues with error message

Tags: jquery

What do these errors mean?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'hover' main.js:31
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slideDown' main.js:12
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slideToggle'
```

I'm very confused because I use the exact same code for another site and it works perfectly with no errors. But when used on a different site I get these errors. New to jQuery so I dont understand the error codes quite well, and so far the stack overflow Q&A's dont seem to have the right answers for this question. Spent some time checking before I posted this. thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of all the scripts tags used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your `<head>`, before including `main.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How about saving the downvote until the OP says whether it was helpful or not?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but now its showing this as well as the previous error messages. GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js  *and sorry Im new I didnt realize anythign about the down vote

Comment: It shouldn't be loading from the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Im using Foundation Zurb dev. kit btw. Not sure if that has anything  to do with this. The part thats confusing me is everything about this code is the same on another site yet Im getting these errors on this one.

Comment: Plus this error code: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined *I'd post my code but its not letting me due to formatting issues.

Comment: Why was this question closed as "Not a real question"? It clearly states at the beginning "What do these errors mean?"

Comment: Because you didn't post any source code or references. My answer was a shot in the dark :)

Comment: thats because, if you read what I wrote in the thread, when I would try to enter the code in it wouldnt let me send it.

Comment: Read this :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx